# Partial loads using Ember Data and relationships

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm attempting to write an XMPP parser that will manage some Ember Data models. Information comes in asynchronously so AFAIK it does not fit neatly into the Adapter pattern. There are a lot of cases where I might get a bit of information, and I want to partially update a model based on this.

For example, a presence message arrives, I want to save this so I can create a history of statuses, but I also want to find and update a contact with this new information. The contact might have lots of other attributes that have nothing to do with presence. There is a one to many relationship between the contact and the presence model.

At the moment I have some code that looks a bit like this:

```
Frabjous.Contact = DS.Model.extend({
  primaryKey: 'jid',
  jid:        DS.attr('jidString'),
  ...
  presence_history: DS.hasMany('Frabjous.Presence'),
});

Frabjous.Presence = DS.Model.extend({
  from:      DS.attr('jidString'),
  ...
  contact:   DS.belongsTo('Frabjous.Contact'),
  didLoad: function(){
    var contact;
    var type              = Frabjous.Contact;
    var contact_id        = this.get('from').toString();
    var contact_client_id = Frabjous.Store.clientIdForId(type, contact_id);

    if( Ember.none(contact_client_id) ){
      // No contact exists, so create one
      Frabjous.Store.load(type,{jid: this.get('from'), presence_history:[this.get('id')]});
      contact = Frabjous.Store.find(type,contact_id);
    }else{
      // Update contact
      contact = Frabjous.Store.find(type,contact_id);

      // !!! this DOES NOT work
      var history = contact.get('presence_history');
      history.addObject(this);
      contact.set('presence_history',history);
    }

    // !!! this DOES work
    this.set('contact',contact);
  }
```

When a new presence message comes in, if no contact exists, it will create one, and build the relationship correctly using the load method. However, if I wish to add the presence record to the presence_history then using `set` does not work. Interestingly, `set` does work when dealing with the Presence side.

I've discovered it is possible to do it with:

```
...
contact.get('presence_history').addObject(this);
...
```

This adds the object, but it does not trigger updates to any of the observers.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, you shouldn't have to set both side of the relationship. Try following the conventions and rename your association:

```
Frabjous.Contact = DS.Model.extend({
  primaryKey: 'jid',
  jid:        DS.attr('jidString'),
  ...
  presences: DS.hasMany('Frabjous.Presence'),
});
```

And then simply associate your records

```
if( Ember.none(contact_client_id) ){
  // No contact exists, so create one
  Frabjous.Store.load(type,{jid: this.get('from'), presence_history:[this.get('id')]});
  contact = Frabjous.Store.find(type,contact_id);
}else{
  // Update contact
  contact = Frabjous.Store.find(type,contact_id);
  this.set('contact', contact);
}
```

If you don't want to change your JSON, you can always configure your model to specify a different key for your association.

Also, I advise you to use `hasReferenceForId` instead of manipulating directly `clientIdForId`.

```
Frabjous.Presence = DS.Model.extend({
  from:      DS.attr('jidString'),
  ...
  contact:   DS.belongsTo('Frabjous.Contact'),
  didLoad: function(){
    var contact;
    var type              = Frabjous.Contact;
    var contact_id        = this.get('from').toString();
    var store             = DS.defaultStore;

    if( !store.hasReferenceForId(Frabjous.Contact, contact_id) ){
      // No contact exists, so create one
      Frabjous.Store.load(type,{jid: this.get('from'), presence_history:[this.get('id')]});
      contact = Frabjous.Store.find(type,contact_id);
    }else{
      ...
    }

    // !!! this DOES work
    this.set('contact',contact);
  }
```